# Gulpjs negate file then re-add it later

Tags: node.js, gulp

There are several question like this one but I believe my situation is slightly different and I cant seem to figure it out.

Given this psuedo code

```
1.) BaseFolder/*.js except the app.js file
2.) BaseFolder/app/model/*js
3.) BaseFolder/app/store/*.js
4.) BaseFolder/app/view/*.js except Viewport.js
5.) BaseFolder/app/view/Viewport.js
6.) BaseFolder/app/controller/*.js
7.) BaseFolder/app.js
```

My problem is that I negate the `app.js` file for example then I want to re-add it at the end. Same deal with the `Viewport.js` file.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Here is one of the many things I've tried:

```
var senchaFiles = [
            baseFolderPath + '/*.js',
            '!' + baseFolderPath + '/app.js',
            baseFolderPath + '/app/model/*.js',
            baseFolderPath + '/app/store/*.js',
            baseFolderPath + '/app/view/*.js',
            '!' + baseFolderPath + '/app/view/Viewport.js',
            baseFolderPath + '/app/view/Viewport.js',
            baseFolderPath + '/app/controller/*.js',
            baseFolderPath + '/app.js'
        ];

return gulp.src(senchaFiles)
            .pipe(concat(folder + '.js'))
            // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            //.pipe(gulp.dest(JS_DIST_FOLDER))
            // .pipe(uglify())
            // .pipe(rename(folder + '.min.js'))
            // .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(JS_DIST_FOLDER));
    });
```

Running this code doesnt add back in the `app.js` or the `Viewport.js` files i negated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gulp uses the [node-glob syntax](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). The code below might be what you're looking for.

```
var senchaFiles = [
  baseFolderPath + '/!(app)*.js', // all, but app.js
  baseFolderPath + '/app/model/*.js',
  baseFolderPath + '/app/store/*.js',
  baseFolderPath + '/app/view/!(Viewport)*.js', // all, but Viewport.js
  baseFolderPath + '/app/view/Viewport.js',
  baseFolderPath + '/app/controller/*.js',
  baseFolderPath + '/app.js'
];
```

Comment: Note, that all negative `!` glob excludes are applied after all includes, irrespective of declaration order. ➝ https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/837